# Load appropriate size image on firefox resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I found this [example](http://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/) of using  tag to use responsive feature. It works fine in Chrome but does't work in firefox as expected. Firefox downloads image which is according to current firefox window width. Is it possible to download image according to window size dinamically on resize without any js?

Comment: available in chrome 38+

Comment: And what? I am asking about firefox. It does't work in firefox as expected :(

Answer (score 1):

There is bug reported regarding the `srcset` attribute

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=870021

As of right now  is available in the dev channel of Chrome and in Firefox 34+. In both cases you’ll need to enable it. In Firefox, head to about:config and search for “dom.image.picture.enabled”. In Chrome you’ll need to go to chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features, enable that feature and restart.

[Reference Site](https://longhandpixels.net/blog/2014/02/complete-guide-picture-element)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I enabled by default http://prntscr.com/7kqlt9 but result is the same. Images are not resized.